# Mocking Camel http endpoint with resource stream in camel

Tags: apache-camel, camelcasing, camel-ftp

I have a route like following

```
from(direct:start)
.process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                   exchange.setProperty("doc_url", "http://myhost:5984/test/record/doc.csv"); 
                }
}).setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
.convertBodyTo(String.class)
.recipientList(header("doc_url")
.split().streaming.process(new MyProcessor());
```

I don't want to run apache couchdb every time for testing. I want to make this http endpoint refer to resource file in the codebase. How to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [Camel AdviceWith](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) feature to intercept/replace endpoints for testing...

```
 camelContext.getRouteDefinition("myRouteId")
  .adviceWith(camelContext, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception
    {
        interceptSendToEndpoint("couchdb:http://localhost/database)
        .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
        .to("http://localhost:5984/test/record/doc.csv");
    }
});
```